# Llamar la funcion principal de mi DLL

Tags: c#

Lo primero que hago es incluir la dll. La clase se llamara igualmente que la de mi programa no se si esto suponga un problema. Lo que quiero una vez agregado es llamar la funcion de mi dll, la clase de la dll sera del siguiente modo:

```
class Program
    {
        static Pool _pool = null;
        static Work _work = null;
        static uint _nonce = 0;
        static long _maxAgeTicks = 20000 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        static uint _batchSize = 100000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    _pool = SelectPool();
                    _work = GetWork();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (_work == null || _work.Age > _maxAgeTicks)
                            _work = GetWork();

                        if (_work.FindShare(ref _nonce, _batchSize))
                        {
                            SendShare(_work.Current);
                            _work = null;
                        }
                        else
                            PrintCurrentState();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write("ERROR: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to try again...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


        private static void ClearConsole()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
            Console.WriteLine("*** Minimal Bitcoin Miner ***");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static Pool SelectPool()
        {
            ClearConsole();
            Print("Chose a Mining Pool 'user:password@url:port' or leave empty to skip.");
            Console.Write("Select Pool: ");
            string login = ReadLineDefault("lithander_2:foo@btcguild.com:8332");
            return new Pool(login);
        }

        private static Work GetWork()
        {
            ClearConsole();
            Print("Requesting Work from Pool...");
            Print("Server URL: " + _pool.Url.ToString());
            Print("User: " + _pool.User);
            Print("Password: " + _pool.Password);
            return _pool.GetWork();
        }

        private static void SendShare(byte[] share)
        {
            ClearConsole();
            Print("*** Found Valid Share ***");
            Print("Share: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Current));
            Print("Nonce: " + Utils.ToString(_nonce));
            Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
            Print("Sending Share to Pool...");
            if (_pool.SendShare(share))
                Print("Server accepted the Share!");
            else
                Print("Server declined the Share!");

            Console.Write("Hit 'Enter' to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static DateTime _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
        private static void PrintCurrentState()
        {
            ClearConsole();
            Print("Data: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Data));
            string current = Utils.ToString(_nonce);
            string max = Utils.ToString(uint.MaxValue);
            double progress = ((double)_nonce / uint.MaxValue) * 100;
            Print("Nonce: " + current + "/" + max + " " + progress.ToString("F2") + "%");
            Print("Hash: " + Utils.ToString(_work.Hash));
            TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - _lastPrint;
            Print("Speed: " + (int)(((_batchSize) / 1000) / span.TotalSeconds) + "Kh/s"); 
            _lastPrint = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private static void Print(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static string ReadLineDefault(string defaultValue)
        {
            //Allow Console.ReadLine with a default value
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (userInput == "")
                return defaultValue;
            else
                return userInput;
        }
    }
```

Lo que quiero es poder llamar la funcion principal desde mi otro proyecto una vez agregada esta dll .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer lo que comentas de forma correcta, deberías encapsular esta funcionalidad en un proyecto de tipo Librería de Clases, y después compartir esa nueva librería en este proyecto de aplicación de consola y en el nuevo que comentas que están intentando utilizar la referencia.

Si te das cuenta, el método Main de la clase Program, no lleva modificador de acceso, eso en C# por defecto toma el valor de private, por lo que nunca va a ser visible fuera de su clase y nunca va a poder ser llamado con Program.Main(new string[]);

Comment: me da el siguiente error Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException uso el siguiente codigo para llamar el main static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.Main(new string[] { });
        } de la funcion que te indique arriba

Comment: eso si cambie static en mi funcion por public

Comment: sigue dandome el mismo error por lo que abrire un nuevo tema

Comment: Si te da ese error, la llamada al método la estás haciendo bien. El problema viene del while, que al no finalizar nunca, no estás gestionándolo bien y se está desbordando.